# Java socket declaration breaks the code execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am working on a project in android studio. The application is a client that connects to  host written in c# using sockets. I am new to java this being my first project I am doing on my own. I am used with sockets in c# and in java I found a lot of similarities, but I encountered a strange problem: everything is fine until a new socket is initialized when the code execution seems to be interrupted. I will post the code than I will explain exactly what is happening.

First part, the main thread:

```
package com.example.alexandru.news;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telecom.Connection;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InterruptedIOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class login extends Activity {

    EditText emadr;
    EditText pasword;
    Button log_in_butt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        log_in_butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        emadr= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmailAdr);
        pasword= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);

    }

    public void loginOnClick(View v)
    {
       final String mesaj=emadr.getText().toString()+"%"+pasword.getText().toString()+"%"+"^STOP^";
        String[] perm={"android.permission.CAMERA"}; int a=200;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(perm,a);
        }



        com.example.alexandru.news.Connection log_in_connection=new com.example.alexandru.news.Connection(mesaj);
        log_in_connection.start();

      }
}
```

The connection class is a class I created in the same folder with the "log in" class(the main class). The code behind the Connection class:

```
package com.example.alexandru.news;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 * Created by Alexandru on 14.08.2016.
 */
public class Connection extends Thread {

    String ip="some ip";
    int port=60000;
    String mesaj;
    Socket soc;

    public Connection(String mesaj) {
        this.mesaj=mesaj;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            int a=2;
            soc= new Socket(ip, port);
            DataOutputStream outstream =new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            byte[] buffer;
            buffer = this.mesaj.getBytes("UTF-8");
            outstream.write(buffer);
            outstream.flush();
            outstream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the app and I press the button everything is executed until the statement `=new Socket(ip,port)` is met when this happen the thread isn't executing anymore (I think). When I am debugging and the breakpoint is set before that problematic line everything works. When that line is highlighted and I press F8 the debugging tab says: "Application is running" and then pressing F8 again doesn't make any changes. If I press the "log in" button again nothing happens.

I am using a USB device to debug the app which is connected to the same network as the PC trough WiFi.No port forward is made. I worked with sockets in a project with my high school team before and we had a java client and a c# host and everything worked. But we were using the Emulator. I used all the ip addresses "ipconfig" gave me I changed the port, nothing happens. It doesn't work. I seems that I am the only one with this problem. Sorry for long post and lack of details.

This is the log:

```
 08-17 12:09:38.875 30326-30326/com.example.alexandru.news D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_MRVL.so
08-17 12:09:38.882 30326-30326/com.example.alexandru.news D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_MRVL.so
08-17 12:09:38.890 30326-30326/com.example.alexandru.news D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_MRVL.so
08-17 12:09:38.898 30326-30326/com.example.alexandru.news D/GC: <tid=30326> OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC Ver SS_rls_pxa988_JB42_R1_RC2_GC13.16 
08-17 12:09:38.914 30326-30326/com.example.alexandru.news D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
08-17 12:09:38.929 30326-30326/com.example.alexandru.news D/WritingBuddyImpl: getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
08-17 12:09:39.054 30326-30326/com.example.alexandru.news D/v_gal: [tid=30326] gralloc_register_buffer: ===>Width = 480, Height = 800, surface = 0x60b55588
08-17 12:09:39.492 30326-30326/com.example.alexandru.news D/v_gal: [tid=30326] gralloc_register_buffer: ===>Width = 480, Height = 800, surface = 0x60e51d40
08-17 12:09:39.984 30326-30326/com.example.alexandru.news D/v_gal: [tid=30326] gralloc_register_buffer: ===>Width = 480, Height = 800, surface = 0x60ef84b8
08-17 12:14:05.617 30326-30350/com.example.alexandru.news D/Er: Eroare
08-17 12:14:17.765 30326-30350/com.example.alexandru.news W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /25.74.114.6 (port 60000) after 1000ms
08-17 12:14:17.765 30326-30350/com.example.alexandru.news W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
08-17 12:14:17.781 30326-30350/com.example.alexandru.news W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
08-17 12:14:17.796 30326-30350/com.example.alexandru.news W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
08-17 12:14:17.796 30326-30350/com.example.alexandru.news W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
08-17 12:14:17.796 30326-30350/com.example.alexandru.news W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
08-17 12:14:17.796 30326-30350/com.example.alexandru.news W/System.err:     at com.example.alexandru.news.Connection.run(Connection.java:45)
08-17 12:14:17.828 30326-30350/com.example.alexandru.news D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
08-17 12:14:17.828 30326-30330/com.example.alexandru.news D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 360K, 17% free 8692K/10472K, paused 11ms+7ms, total 60ms
```

Comment: `"some ip";`. No tell us exactly which ip you are using and why. You are sure you get no IOException? Look in the LogCat.

Comment: `am using a USB device `.  ??? I use Android devices to test Android apps.

Comment: Put some Log statements in the run() so you better see what happens. Also in the catch.

Comment: INTERNET permission in manifest?

Comment: @greenapps 1st question: 25.74.114.6; 2nd USB device is called in the IDE; 3rd No exception is catched 4th Yes. I included that

Comment: I also tried to call Socket.setSoTimeout and the same thing happened....

Comment: You did not tell what happens. Dont use the debugger to tell what happens. And only mentioning an ip withhout telling why is not informative.

Comment: Your socket creation line is blocked for up to about a minute trying to connect. After that it would throw a `ConnectException`. This sequence of events would mean that there is a firewall in the way.

Comment: Ok, I will test that

Comment: @EJP you are right. It gives me a socket timeout exception.

Comment: And note that it is not the declaration but the initialization that is doing that.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, I will look into it. At least I know where to look now. Thanks!

Comment: @EJP it looks like I used the wrong ip address. If I use a client on my pc it works, but my device isn't connecting. I don't know what IP address to use. I read that I need the wifi ip address, but I don't know how to get that (I am using win 8.1). Also I read that I need a port forward on that port which is strange cause the device and the pc are in the same network.